# rel="prerender" load event? Notify users when prerender finishes

Tags: javascript, html, prerender

On page A, I dynamically insert a prerender tag pointing to page B: `<link rel="prerender" href="page B"/>`.

I want to know if `prerender` fires an event when it is done loading page B which I can access from the javascript on page A.

If browsers don't have any support for this, is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the load and error events are not fired with the **rel="prerender"**, the same in Chrome/Firefox (I don't know why).

Instead of that I use **rel="preload"** and everything is working fine (but just for Chrome)

Additionally you can to add the type of asset with **as** parameter

```
<link rel="preload" as="document" href="some.html">
```

My Typescript Method to create a link to download is the next:

```
private createLinkToPreload(externalHref: string): HTMLElement {
  let linkElement = document.createElement("link");
  linkElement.rel = "preload";
  linkElement.href = externalHref;

  let me = this;
  linkElement.onload = () => {me.onElementPreloaded(externalHref)};
  linkElement.onerror = () => {me.onElementPreloadError(externalHref)};

  return linkElement;
}

private onElementPreloaded(externalHref: string) {
  console.log(`${externalHref} preloaded`);
}

private onElementPreloadError(externalHref: string) {
  console.log(`Error while preloading ${externalHref}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`link` tag fires a load event when it's done loading.

```
link.addEventListener('load', func(e));
```

or

```
link.onload = func;
```

For maximum browser support, don't use `link`. Just get the file using AJAX.